# Button don't executes JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm interested on learn about the programming world and I'm trying some basics about making simple web plugins. The thing is I'm not able to make my button run a little JS, any tip? Thanks a lot!!

```
<button id="button1" onclick="myFunction()">Start the script</button> 
<script type="application/javascript">
document.addEventListener("button1", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
var para = document.createElement("p");
var ht1 = '<p class="pop">Working</p>';
var ht2 = '<p class="image"><img src="image.png"></p>';
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why dont you think it's running? You don't do anything with the created variables.

Comment: If you use `addEventListener` take 5 minutes and read documentation how to use it.

Comment: +@dfsq, `addEventListener` is used by binding a function to an event, so the syntax is `myElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction)`.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan thanks for answer! im sorry for being newbie, just started some days ago in school to test things

Comment: @Jean, you're welcome, just next time, make sure to read things through before asking here, and be sure that the problem doesn't have a solution that you've just overlooked. Good luck!

Comment: @YaakovAinspan the button with that edit keeps not working too :/ how i should write it ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/n8yLfxrs/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want that something would happen you need to write that in the function. You already wrote variables, but you did nothing with them, so nothing could happen.

**Try this :**

```html
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
  }
</script>
```